# How to build a query string with a complex object that includes an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, model-view-controller, query-string

My google-fu is just not working today.  I have found many similar questions but none that fit my particular scenario. I'm trying to build a query string to pass data down to my MVC controller without using a post because I'm using windows.open to display a PDF file.

The object in javascript looks like this

```
{DateValue: "05/31/2020", 
 StringArray: ["String 1", "String 2", etc], 
 StringValue: "Some String Value"}
```

When converting my object to parameters using $.param(), the StringArray is turned into

`StringArray[]=String 1&StringArray[]=String 2`

And the call to the controller is

```
window.open('/{controller}/{action}?' + $.param(data), '_blank');
```

data being the above object.

**ViewModel**

```
public class Model
{
   public DateTime DateValue {get;set;}
   public List<string> StringArray {get;set;}
   public string StringValue {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller Call**

```
public FileContentResult Action(Model model)
{...}
```

For whatever reason MVC isn't recognizing the string array. The model has the correct values for the DateValue and StringValue properties, but the StringArray is always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up refactoring the call to make an ajax call first, putting the view model into cache, then return a url with a cache key back which is used in the window.open call.  It requires making two server calls but at least then we eliminated the need to put all the data into the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `JSON.stringify()`

```
const data = {DateValue: "05/31/2020", 
 StringArray: ["String 1", "String 2", etc], 
 StringValue: "Some String Value"}

window.open('/{controller}/{action}?data=' + JSON.stringify(data), '_blank');
```

and `JSON.parse`

```
//PARAMS = how you ever you planned to retrieve them from the request
const data = JSON.parse(PARAMS.data);

console.log(data); 
/* 
// outputs: 
{
  DateValue: "05/31/2020", 
  StringArray: ["String 1", "String 2", etc], 
  StringValue: "Some String Value"
}
*/
```

Comment: I tried switching $.param to JSON.stringify and the MVC controller doesn't recognize the query string, my object is null

Comment: How are you accessing the query string?

Comment: Using MVC.  It's making the call to the controller in the windows.open, using the parameters created by $.param.  The controller action takes in the view model, which contains all the properties.  It's actually the same model going to the UI that is being received back. The Date and String values are populated but the String Array is not.